# AE - Tracking in Comp different when played backwards?

Tags: video, after-effects, editing

I've come across a rather strange phenomenon in After-Effects.

Here's what I have:

I tracked some shaky footage and applied the tracked motion to a null. Then, a camera follows that null, thus stabilizing my footage. It all looks great and so I precomped everything. Now I want to play the comp as a boomerang - so first at 100% speed and then at -100% (playing backwards).

The strange thing is: When the comp is played forward, everything is smooth and ok. But when the same comp is played at -100% speed (backwards), the tracking is way off and jolts around.

I have checked for invisible layers, cleared my cache, restarted the program, checked every layer in the comp, made sure that these really were the same comps, etc. etc.

If you know what is causing this strange behavior, any tips are appreciated. thanks :)